# How Can I Compile Firefox and Include a Few Extensions?

Tags: firefox

I need to be able to compile firefox and bundle it with a few extensions so when people download it the extensions are already there.

I was wondering if anyone can point me to some documentation. I have been searching for hours and can't seem to find anything like that.

Thanks,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to specifically 'compile' Firefox and are using Windows, you can create a simple batch (.bat) file to execute the Firefox installer and then the extensions installers in order.  Alternatively, you can also use a Powershell (.ps1) script.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out CCK or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of copying the extensions contents to the extension guid directory of FireFox. First unzip the extensions files (xpi files are just a normal zip files) then copy them.

You can do that automatically by writing simple shell scripts for Linux/Unix/Mac, or, batch files for Windows XP and PowerShell for Vista (as John Dunagan mentioned).

Check the forth post in the following thread 
 
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=586672&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for recompiling it.
Just create an install procedure (a script actually), which is gonna install firefox first and then the extensions afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling won't help at all. The extensions aren't compiled into Firefox, because doing so would make Firefox have to be recompiled every time an extension is installed. Just follow the above answers to automatically install the extensions.